# Ajax in WORDPRESS Not Working properly when page/post name is set as permlink

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have problem with AJAX in WORDPRESS.
When I set permlinks as default AJAX works perfectly but as when I am changing it to postname ajax responce gives me 404 status.
Here is my html code and javascript code which makes ajax call.

```js
<script>
           
          $("#dp").datepicker({           
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          showOn: 'both',
          onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
           $( "#dp" ).datepicker( "option",selectedDate );
           
           
           
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
           {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           }
           else
             {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
             {
              alert(xmlhttp.status);
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {
              //alert("hi");
              //document.getElementById("pdf").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              window.location.href = response;  
              //alert("ddd");
             }
             }
           
           xmlhttp.open("POST","http://xyz.in/wp-content/themes/xyz/option_post_date.php?postdate="+selectedDate,true);
           xmlhttp.send();
          }
          });
         </script>
```

```html
 <form action="" method="post" id="newsdate">
   <input type="hidden" id="dp" name="dp"/>
 </form>
```

Here is Ajax file php code

```html
<?php 
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-blog-header.php");
//require_once(".../wp-blog-header.php"); ?>
<?php 

$postDate=$_GET['postdate'];
/*function wpa57065_filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts in the last 30 days
 $postDate=$_GET['postdate'];
 $query="select * from wp_posts where post_type='newspaper'";
 $data=mysql_query($query);
 $dataset=mysql_fetch_array($data);
 $datedata=$dataset['post_date'];
 $time=substr($datedata,-8);
 $newDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($postDate));
    $where .= " AND post_date = '" . $newDate . " ".$time ."'";
    return $where;
}*/
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'NewsPaper',
'numberposts'=>1,
'meta_query' =>array(
array(
 'key'=>'publish_date',
 'value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($postDate)),
 'compare' => '='
)));

$newspapers[0] = new WP_Query( $args );

$flag=$newspapers[0]->posts;
$postid=$flag[0]->ID;
if(isset($_GET['pageid']))
{
 $pageNo=$_GET['pageid']; 
}
else
{
 $pageNo=1; 
}

$meta_values = get_post_meta( $postid);
   

echo do_shortcode('[gview file="'.$meta_values['page_'.$pageNo.'_pdf'][0].'" width=100% height=800px]');
?><?php
wp_reset_postdata();      
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using ajax the wordpress way?

for the ajax url:

```
"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"
```

next to the postdate that you pass you have to pass the name of the function that you want to call in php:

```
action="get_posts"
```

register the function in the functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_posts', 'get_posts_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_posts', 'get_posts_callback');

function get_posts_callback(){
    $postdate = filter_var($_POST['postdate'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_STRING);
    //echo your stuff
    die('');
}
```

here you can find a good example: http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/